# In kubernetes python client, curl command returns the output in str and I am expecting output in json format

Tags: python, json, kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client

I am creating a program in kubernetes python client, and which curls an url inside the pod and expect the output in `json`, instead the output comes in form of `str`. Following is my program:

```
from kubernetes import client, config, watch
from kubernetes.stream import stream
config.load_kube_config()
k8s_corev1 = client.CoreV1Api()

def run_command_inside_pod(api_instance, pod, ns, exec_command):
    api_response = stream(api_instance.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec, pod, ns,
                          command=exec_command,
                          stderr=True, stdin=False,
                          stdout=True, tty=False)
    return api_response


def metrics_datastore_check():
    """

    :param name:
    :return:
    """
    name = "metrics-datastore-0"

    print("Waiting for pod %s to get ready." % name)
    exec_command = ['curl', '--silent', '-i', 'localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty']
    es_status = run_command_inside_pod(k8s_corev1,name,"default",exec_command)
    print (es_status)

    print (type(es_status))

metrics_datastore_check()
```

The above program returns the following output:

```
(env) [root@ip-10-0-1-48 k8s_Client]# python2 es_pod.py 
Waiting for pod metrics-datastore-0 to get ready.
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 470

{
  "cluster_name" : "metrics-datastore",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 2,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
}

<type 'str'>
```

As you can clearly see the type of return value is `str` and hence I am unable to parse it properly using json tools. Could anyone please help me either to get that output in form of `dict` or converting that `str` to `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

[json.loads()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) -> This parses a string object and returns json object

```
import json
json_object = json.loads(es_status)
print(json_object['status'])
```

Comment: No, It doesn't converts into dict, so that I can use it like `print(json_object['status'])`